# Is there an API of Google App Engine provided to better configure the Bigtable besides Datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

According to the Bigtable original article, a column key of a Bigtable is named using "family:qualifier" syntax where column family names must be printable but qualifiers may be arbitrary strings. In the application I am working on, I would like to specify the qualifiers using Chinese words (or phrase). Is it possible to do this in Google App Engine? Is there a Bigtable API other than provided datastore API? It seems Google is tightly protecting its platform for good reasons.

Thanks in advance.

Marvin

Answer (score 2):

The Datastore is the only interface to the underlying storage on App Engine. You should be able to use any valid UTF-8 string as a kind name, key name, or property name, however.

Comment: Thanks. If that is the case, how do I make use of the Bigtable concept of Column Family and Columns in Datastore. Or how do I relate Column Family and Columns in Bigtable to Datastore?

Comment: You should probably not worry about it.  The GAE data store does a lot of stuff behind the scenes so that developers don't have to read research papers to use the tool.

Comment: @marvinchen What @Bob said. Learn about how to use the Datastore, independent of what it's built on underneath.